# How do you create a Uniq ID in Google Sheets using apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im looking at creating a simple Uniq ID after column A has information entered and need for the ID to show on column I. I want to call it Trip Number and display Driver-John0001 and so forth using google sheets script. Sorry I'm new to this so I don't know the lingo

The current code I had found works but now I need it a bit different. This is what my results show Driver:1611710811706

I would like to pull Driver-John0001. Where the name John is generated by the column labeled Driver or column D
How do I change it to add the value on column D + 4 digit numbers that don't repeat?

[image]

```js
function TripID () {
     { var sheetVals = [
      ["DriverLog","Driver:","",9,1]
    ];}
 
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
      //Loop through every sheet value
      for(var i = 0; i < sheetVals.length; i++){
        var sheetID  = sheetVals[i][0],
            frontStr = sheetVals[i][1],
            backStr  = sheetVals[i][2],
            IDcol    = sheetVals[i][3],
            editCol  = sheetVals[i][4];
    
        var offset = IDcol - editCol;
    
        if(sheet.getName() === sheetID){
          var date = new Date().getTime();
          var newID = frontStr+date+backStr;   
      
          //Check the location of the active cell
          var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
          if( selectedCell.getColumn() === editCol) {
      
            //Update the ID Column
            var cellToChange = selectedCell.offset(0,offset);
            if(cellToChange.isBlank()){
            cellToChange.setValue(newID);
            };
          };
        };
      };
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you will never need more than 9999 IDs, then you could modify your code with the following steps to accomplish this. Note that this solution will allow you to create a (nearly) unlimited number of ID numbers, but after 9999, the length of the id numbers will vary.

1. Use the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) to initialize a counter for creating IDs

```
  function createIdProperty() {
     PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('idCounter', '0');
  }
  
  // run this once to create the idCounter property
  createIdProperty();

  // To test that your property was created you can run this
  Logger.log(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('idCounter')); // logs '0'
```

2. Create a function to get the next counterId number from Script Properties as a string with 0s replacing empty digits ( 1 => '0001', 2 => '0002', 3 => '0003')

```
function getUniqueIdNumber() {
  var currentIdNum = +PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('idCounter'); //get counter as a number
  currentIdNum++; // increment counter by 1
  currentIdNum+=''; // convert counter back to a string
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('idCounter', currentIdNum); // store the new counter in properies
  while (currentIdNum.length < 4) {
    currentIdNum = '0'+currentIdNum;
  }
  return currentIdNum;
}
```

3. modify your original code to use `getUniqueIdNumber` instead of `date` for creating your id

Change

```
var newID = frontStr+date+backStr;
```

To

```
var idNumber = getUniqueIdNumber();
var newID = frontStr+idNumber;
```

Note that you can replace `frontStr` and `backStr` with any variables you want.

Comment: Why are you limiting it to 9999 uuids?

Comment: @raygun thanks for the update. This is still new to me and am used to creating formulas in excel. I'm not sure how i would string all of that together or what actual parts in my script i'll replace.

Comment: @Aerials I'm not really. The question asks for 4 digit numbers that don't repeat.

Comment: @JaimeQuintero Here are your steps: (1) Open the code editor for your project. (2) Make sure that your project has a title (3) Paste the code from step 1 of my answer into the top of the code editor (4) Select `createIdProperty` from the function dropdown and click run (5) delete the code that you pasted in step 3 (6) find `var newID = frontStr+date+backStr;` in your original code (7) replace that line with `var idNumber = getUniqueIdNumber(); 
var newID = frontStr+idNumber;`

Comment: @RayGun I might have screwed this up. I'm getting error ReferenceError: sheet is not defined and then ReferenceError: frontStr is not defined

Comment: @JaimeQuintero can you share the sheet with me that contains the script?

Comment: @RayGun yes, can you provide me with your email? or can I attach here?

Comment: @RayGun thanks for the help. This works perfect